# C++ cout char 'return' character from file appears twice

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a program that encrypts files based on how Nazi Germany's Enigma machine worked, but without the flaw :P.

I have a function that gets a character at n point in a file, but when it returns a return character and I cout << it, it's like it hit enter twice.
IE if I loop cout-ing from i++ points in a file the individual lines in the terminal appear separated

by more returns

than one.

Here's the function:

```
char charN(string pathOf, int pointIn){
    char r = NULL;
      // NULL so I can tell when it doesn't return a character.
    int sizeOf; //to store the found size of the file.
    ifstream cf; //to store the Character Found.
    ifstream siz; //used later to get the size of the file

    siz.open(pathOf.c_str());

    siz.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    sizeOf = siz.tellg();  // these get the length of the file and put it in sizeOf.

    cf.open(pathOf.c_str());
    if(cf.is_open() && pointIn < sizeOf){ //if not open, or if the character to get is farther out than the size of the file, let the function return the error condition: 'NULL'.
        cf.seekg(pointIn); // move to the point in the file where the character should be, get it, and get out.
         cf.get(r);
         cf.close();
    }
    return r;
}
```

It works correctly if I use cout << '\n', but what's different about returns from a file and '\n'?
Or is there something else I'm missing?
I've been googling about but I can't find anything remotely similar to my problem, thanks in advance.

I'm using Code::Blocks 13.12 as my compiler if that matters.

Comment: NULL doesn't work as an invalid character. It works as an invalid pointer.

Comment: You are using not one, but two open-close cycles and two seekg operations to get a single character from a file. This is not how files are intended to be used.

Comment: I needed to work with a single character at a time do to how the enigma machine works.

Comment: NULL does work how I'm using it though, but I'm not one for the term "If it ain't broke: don't fix it", If there's something else I could do please let me know.

Comment: The enigma machine didn't use fstreams at all. "Single characterst a time" doesn't necessarily mean "using fstream in the least efficient way possible".

Comment: Look at `fgetc`. What *type* does it return? What *value* signals the "no character" condition? What you have wrote maybwork in your specific application and/or with your specific data set, but it will not work in in oher situations. So this piece of code is counter-roductove as a learning block.

Comment: charN returns a char, NULL is the no character condition which somehow works, I'll look into fgetc, thank you; but I still don't know why returns are doubled.

Comment: You are getting incorrect results because relative seekg doesn't work with text mode files. Don't access your file this way. Enigma is a *stream* cipher, that's what "one character at a time" means. Use normal istream functions.

Comment: The obfuscation tables (rollers) for enigma3 contain tabs, spaces, and returns, as well as the other qwerty keyboard characters, so why is return the only character that seems to double? I'm encrypting files, not just messages. I appreciate you trying to help me learn more appropriate coding techniques, but my problem still stands; I'll try fgetc/getc and get back to you.

Comment: Relative seek on text files is **undefined**. It may cause your function to return double line feeds, or format your hard disk, or launch a nuclear strike against Mars. There's no telling.

Comment: I was using seek to read till i got to the spot, then get to return the character at that spot. I tried testing for every one and two combo of \n and \r, no results, perhaps this double return character is something else entirely?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2d6fx99.aspx (look at the "do not use" part).

Comment: I should also mention why I use two seekg()s; once to get the size of the file, another to get to the point in the file where the character is sopposed to be. It was the only thing I could find for file size. if say you have a message 12 characters long, and you set poinIn to 15, what happens then? Thats to prevent charN()'s "character not in range" explosion of erorrrr that has not been tested yet...

Comment: If you use `seekg` with an offset on a text file, **anything** could happen.  Google "undefined behavior". It's a wrong method of getting to the nth character. Don't use it. "But it almost works for me, how can I tweak it so"... You can't. End of story.

Comment: But, but it's the only thing I could find for file size!

Comment: What if I check for high AND low pointIn?

Comment: Finding size is OK. It is not relative (i.e. the offset is zero). Moving to nth character is not OK.

Comment: And you suggest fgetc? But I don't know how to USE fgetc! "Learn then - n.m."

Comment: I would need to redirect the position with SOMETHING for fgetc, if not seekg then what? You mean fgetc n times?

Comment: No I'm not. I said "look at its return type", not "use it". I said that because NULL as a no-character condition is wrong. Learn from fgetc how to signal a no-character condition. This is unrelated to seekg. If you don't know what to do with fgetc, look at istream::get which is the same thing. You can use it if you want.

Comment: So, return EOF? I mean, it works. :l

Comment: You should also ask yourself why you need charN in the first place. It is slow and resource hungry. Perhaps you should avoid it altogether.

Comment: Yes, return EOF, and the type should be int, not char.

Comment: As a quick & simple character streaming service for the Enigma3 code! ^u^

Comment: It's, not exactly an encryption program per se...

Comment: A stream is not an array. Look at the istream class. That's an example of a stream. Does it have a "get nth character" function? No.

Comment: I can only repeat what I already said. Enigma is a stream cipher. You need nothing beyond `istream` and its most basic method `get`. Did real Enigma machines have to ask the operator "now type ze 15th character bitte"?

Comment: The real enigma machines were a circuit and bulb. :l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this is on a windows machine? In windows new lines in text files are representing by \r\n.

- \r = carriage return
- \n = line feed

It's possible that you are couting each one separately and that the output buffer is creating a new line for each one.

Comment: I added some code to check for that but it didn't change anything, so I assume not;thanks though. Yes WIN7

Comment: You were right, it's a double \n, I skipped 1 character after each line feed and it works correctly, so it's a long road of testing and tweaking from here; thanks btw. I mean, I made a program read the file, but instead of just couting the character I couted =\\N= or =\\R= for respectove characters, there were a bunch of =\\N==\\N= on the screen. :l